# What is the best way to do this replace a list of characters with '-' in a string.?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I want to replace these symbols with '-' and I know there should be a better way than doing this:

```
if '/' in var1:
    var1= var1.replace('/', '-')
if '#' in var1:
    var1= var1.replace('#', '-')
if ';' in var1:
    var1 = var1.replace(';', '-')
if ':' in var1:
    var1= var1.replace(':', '-')
```

This is what I tried, which is clearly wrong and I'm not able to properly optimize it.

```
str = 'Testing PRI/Sec (#434242332;PP:432:133423846,335)'
a = ['#',':',';','/']
print([str.replace(i,'-') for i in str])
```

replaceAll doesn't work, gives me an error saying str does not has that attribute.

```
str.replaceAll("[<>]", "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = 'Testing PRI/Sec (#434242332;PP:432:133423846,335)'
a = ['#',':',';','/']

print(''.join('-' if ch in a else ch for ch in s))
```

Prints:

```
Testing PRI-Sec (-434242332-PP-432-133423846,335)
```

Or using `re`:

```
s = 'Testing PRI/Sec (#434242332;PP:432:133423846,335)'
a = ['#',':',';','/']

import re
print(re.sub('|'.join(re.escape(i) for i in a), '-', s))
```

Prints:

```
Testing PRI-Sec (-434242332-PP-432-133423846,335)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `str.translate()`?

```
# make a translation table that replaces any of "#:;/" with hyphens
hyphenator = str.maketrans({c: "-" for c in "#:;/"})
# use str.translate to apply it
print("Testing PRI/Sec (#434242332;PP:432:133423846,335)".translate(hyphenator))
```

Or, even faster, use a compiled regex:

```
compiled_re = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(i) for i in "#:;/"))
print(compiled_re.sub("-", "Testing PRI/Sec (#434242332;PP:432:133423846,335)"))
```

Both of these methods are much faster than the other methods proposed (at least on that input):

```
import re
import timeit

s = "Testing PRI/Sec (#434242332;PP:432:133423846,335)"
a = ["#", ":", ";", "/"]
hyphenator = str.maketrans({c: "-" for c in "#:;/"})


def str_translate():
    s.translate(hyphenator)


def join_generator():
    "".join("-" if ch in a else ch for ch in s)


def append_in_loop():
    temp = ""
    for i in s:
        if i in a:
            temp += "-"
        else:
            temp += i


def re_sub():
    re.sub("|".join(re.escape(i) for i in a), "-", s)

def compiled_re_sub():
    compiled_re.sub("-", s)

for method in [str_translate, join_generator, re_sub, append_in_loop, compiled_re_sub]:
    # run a million iterations and report the total time
    print("{} took a total of {}s".format(method.__name__, timeit.timeit(method)))
```

Results on my machine:

```
str_translate took a total of 1.1160085709998384s
join_generator took a total of 4.599312704987824s
re_sub took a total of 4.101858579088002s
append_in_loop took a total of 4.257988628000021s
compiled_re_sub took a total of 1.0353244650177658s
```

Comment: If you `re.compile` first the regular expression outside the `re_sub()` function, the regex is fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through add each character to the temp variable unless it is in the list "a" if it is in the list just replace it by adding "-" to the variable instead.

```
str = 'Testing PRI/Sec (#434242332;PP:432:133423846,335)'
a = ['#',':',';','/']
temp = ''
for i in str:
    if i in a:
        temp = temp + "-"
    else:
        temp = temp + i
print(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use re package

```
import re
string = 'Testing PRI/Sec (#434242332;PP:432:133423846,335)'
result = re.sub('[#:;/]',"-", string)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
Testing PRI-Sec (-434242332-PP-432-133423846,335)
```